# Placing canvas inside Div element

Tags: geometry, itext7

I am trying to create a circle in itext 7 and then place this circle anywhere in I need to in the document.

The document is laid out using divs and I have managed to create the circle using a `PdfCanvas`.

Below is a snippet of what I am trying to achieve and there may well be a better way to do this:

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

  Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

  PdfPage pdfPage = pdfDoc.addNewPage();

  Div div = new Div();                        
  div.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
  div.setHeight(10.0F);
  div.add(new Paragraph(" ").setFont(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.COURIER_BOLD)));  
  doc.add(div);

  PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);  
   Color white = Color.WHITE;  
   Color black = Color.BLACK;

   canvas.setColor(white, true)
   .setStrokeColor(black) 
   .circle(15, 800, 8)      
   .fillStroke();     

   canvas.beginText()      
   .setFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.COURIER_BOLD), 10)               
   .setColor(black, true)
   .moveText(15 - 3, 800 - 3)
   .showText("1")
   .endText();

  doc.close();
```

If there is a correct way of wrapping some text (number) in a circle that can be positioned inside a div then I will happily change to this method if someone can point me towards a tutorial or some documentation I can follow.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for an easy way to do this then you can override the `draw` method of `Div`.

```
public class Circle extends Div
{
@Override
public IRenderer getRenderer()
{
    return new CircleRenderer(this);
}

private class CircleRenderer extends DivRenderer
{

    public CircleRenderer(final Circle circle)
    {
        super(circle);
        setPadding(PADDING);
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(final DrawContext drawContext)
    {
        final PdfCanvas canvas = drawContext.getCanvas();


        final Rectangle area = this.occupiedArea.getBBox();
        final float x = area.getX();
        final float y = area.getY();

        canvas.circle(x, y, 8);

        canvas.fillStroke();            

        super.draw(drawContext);
    }
}
}
```

After I draw the canvas I need to do some correction of the x and y positions and same for any text placed inside the circle.